# convert/simplify sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, db2

Good day everyone! 
I was trying to convert this db2 code into sql:

```
CREATE VIEW TBSDB2P.V_ADVICE_SLIPS as select * from ( select AS.AS_NUMBER,AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, DEP.TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, DEP.FACE_VALUE, nullif(0,0) Number_of_shares, nullif(0,0) Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, DEP.RATE, nullif(0,0) YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS AS INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_DEPOSIT DEP on (AS.AS_NUMBER = DEP.AS_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( DEP.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) UNION ALL select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, nullif(0,0) FACE_VALUE, EQT.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_SHARES, EQT.Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, nullif(0,0) YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS AS INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_EQUITY EQT on (AS.AS_NUMBER = EQT.AS_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) UNION ALL select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR, GS.Price_Per_100, GS.AWARDED_FACE_VALUE as FACE_VALUE, nullif(0,0) Number_of_shares, nullif(0,0) Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, GS.YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS AS INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_GS GS on (AS.AS_NUMBER = GS.AS_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) UNION ALL select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, PREF.FACE_VALUE, PREF.DONE_NUMBER_OF_SHARES, PREF.Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, PREF.YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS AS INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_PREF PREF on ( AS.AS_NUMBER = PREF.AS_NUMBER ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) UNION ALL select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, PREP.FACE_VALUE, PREP.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_SHARES, PREP.Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, nullif(0,0) YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS AS INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_PREP PREP on ( AS.AS_NUMBER = PREP.AS_NUMBER ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) UNION ALL select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR, OSEC.Price_Per_100, OSEC.AWARDED_FACE_VALUE as  FACE_VALUE, nullif(0,0) Number_of_shares, nullif(0,0) Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, OSEC.YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS AS INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_OSEC OSEC on ( AS.AS_NUMBER = OSEC.AS_NUMBER ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) UNION ALL select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, nullif(0,0) FACE_VALUE, PF.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_UNITS as number_of_shares, nullif(0,0) Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, nullif(0,0) YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS AS INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_POOLED_FUNDS PF on (AS.AS_NUMBER = PF.AS_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) ) as ALL_AS;
```

but it returns an error that my view's select statement contains subquery.

I tried to "chop" it into seperate select sql statements and this is what I got:

```
   select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, 
   AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, 
   DEP.TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, DEP.FACE_VALUE, nullif(0,0) Number_of_shares, nullif(0,0) Price_per_share,
   AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, DEP.RATE, nullif(0,0) YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, 
   AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE,
   ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, 
   AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID 

   FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS 

   AS 

   INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_DEPOSIT DEP on (TBSDB2P.AS.AS_NUMBER = DEP.AS_NUMBER) 
   LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( DEP.as_number = ALLOC.as_number )
   LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) 
   LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE )
   LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) 
   UNION ALL 

   select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, 
   AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, 
   ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, 
   nullif(0,0) FACE_VALUE, EQT.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_SHARES, EQT.Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, 
   nullif(0,0) RATE, nullif(0,0) YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, 
   AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, 
   ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, 
   ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE,  AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
   FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS

   AS

   INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_EQUITY EQT on (AS.AS_NUMBER = EQT.AS_NUMBER) 
   LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) 
   LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) 
   LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) 
   LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) 
   UNION ALL 

   select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status,
   AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
   nullif(0,0) TENOR, GS.Price_Per_100, GS.AWARDED_FACE_VALUE as FACE_VALUE, nullif(0,0) Number_of_shares,
   nullif(0,0) Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, GS.YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
   AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, 
   BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID 
   FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS 

    AS 

    INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_GS GS on (AS.AS_NUMBER = GS.AS_NUMBER)
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) 
    UNION ALL

    select
    AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status,
    AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
    nullif(0,0) TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, PREF.FACE_VALUE, PREF.DONE_NUMBER_OF_SHARES, PREF.Price_per_share, 
    AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, PREF.YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER,
    ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
    ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID 
    FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS 

    AS 

    INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_PREF PREF on ( AS.AS_NUMBER = PREF.AS_NUMBER ) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number )
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE )
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) 

    UNION ALL 
    select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, 
    AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
    nullif(0,0) TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100, PREP.FACE_VALUE, PREP.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_SHARES, PREP.Price_per_share,
    AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, nullif(0,0) YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER,
    ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
    ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID 
    FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS         
    AS

    INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_PREP PREP on ( AS.AS_NUMBER = PREP.AS_NUMBER ) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE ) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) 

    UNION ALL 
    select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status,
    AS.Transaction_Type, AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR,
    OSEC.Price_Per_100, OSEC.AWARDED_FACE_VALUE as  FACE_VALUE, nullif(0,0) Number_of_shares, nullif(0,0) Price_per_share,
    AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, nullif(0,0) RATE, OSEC.YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER,
    ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
    ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE, AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
    FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS AS 
    INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_OSEC OSEC on ( AS.AS_NUMBER = OSEC.AS_NUMBER )
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number )
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE )
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE) 

    UNION ALL 
    select AS.AS_NUMBER, AS.CREATE_TIME_STAMP, AS.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER, AS.Record_Status, AS.Approval_Status, AS.Transaction_Type,
    AS.Value_Date, AS.ASSET_CLASS_CODE, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME, nullif(0,0) TENOR, nullif(0,0) Price_Per_100,
    nullif(0,0) FACE_VALUE, PF.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_UNITS as number_of_shares, nullif(0,0) Price_per_share, AS.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT, 
    nullif(0,0) RATE, nullif(0,0) YTM, AS.ISSUE_CODE, ACCT.USER_ID as ACCOUNT_OFFICER, AS.ACCOUNT_OFFICER as MAKER, ACCT.ARRANGEMENT, 
    ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE, ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE, ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE, BANK.REGION_ID, AS.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE, ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE as ISSUER_CODE,
    AS.AS_TYPE, AS.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
    FROM TBSDB2P.IMS_AS 
    AS 
    INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_POOLED_FUNDS PF on (AS.AS_NUMBER = PF.AS_NUMBER)
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC on ( AS.as_number = ALLOC.as_number ) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT on (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER) 
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK on ( ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE )
    LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE on (AS.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE)
```

Will someone help me in organizing this query? thanks..

Comment: We couldn't start with something simpler?

Comment: Please help us by simplifying it further. Currently, it's in the TL;DR form.

Comment: NULLIF is a new one on me. How about IFNULL or COALESCE() (which conforms to the sql standard). Also AS is a reserved word

Comment: actually, I tried to simplify it.. the main problem was there's a subquery in the create view's select statement. I tried to chop these subqueries into various select statements but there are some errors.. btw,  I found the error.. the name of table is AS when it should be ims_as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a monster!! I think i've got it. I'm presuming that TBSDB2P is a database name:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_ADVICE_SLIPS 
(
  AS_NUMBER,
  CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
  ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER,
  Record_Status,
  Approval_Status,
  Transaction_Type,
  Value_Date,
  ASSET_CLASS_CODE,
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCOUNT_NAME,
  TENOR,
  Price_Per_100,
  FACE_VALUE,
  Number_of_shares,
  Price_per_share,
  SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
  RATE,
  YTM,
  ISSUE_CODE,
  ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
  MAKER,
  ARRANGEMENT,
  PRODUCT_CODE,
  TBG_UNIT_CODE,
  BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE,
  REGION_ID,
  COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
  COUNTER_PARTY_CODE AS ISSUER_CODE,
  AS_TYPE,
  REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
) 
AS 

SELECT
  AS1.AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
  AS1.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.Record_Status,
  AS1.Approval_Status,
  AS1.Transaction_Type,
  AS1.Value_Date,
  AS1.ASSET_CLASS_CODE,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
  DEP.TENOR,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_Per_100,
  DEP.FACE_VALUE,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Number_of_shares,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_per_share,
  AS1.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
  DEP.RATE,
  NULLIF(0, 0) YTM,
  AS1.ISSUE_CODE,
  ACCT.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
  AS1.ACCOUNT_OFFICER AS MAKER,
  ACCT.ARRANGEMENT,
  ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE,
  ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE,
  ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE,
  BANK.REGION_ID,
  AS1.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
  AS1.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE AS ISSUER_CODE,
  AS1.AS_TYPE,
  AS1.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
FROM
  TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS AS1
  INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_DEPOSIT DEP ON (AS1.AS_NUMBER = DEP.AS_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC ON (DEP.as_number = ALLOC.as_number)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT ON (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK ON (ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE ON (AS1.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE)

UNION ALL

SELECT
  AS1.AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
  AS1.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.Record_Status,
  AS1.Approval_Status,
  AS1.Transaction_Type,
  AS1.Value_Date,
  AS1.ASSET_CLASS_CODE,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
  NULLIF(0, 0) TENOR,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_Per_100,
  NULLIF(0, 0) FACE_VALUE,
  EQT.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_SHARES,
  EQT.Price_per_share,
  AS1.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
  NULLIF(0, 0) RATE,
  NULLIF(0, 0) YTM,
  AS1.ISSUE_CODE,
  ACCT.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
  AS1.ACCOUNT_OFFICER AS MAKER,
  ACCT.ARRANGEMENT,
  ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE,
  ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE,
  ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE,
  BANK.REGION_ID,
  AS1.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
  ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE AS ISSUER_CODE,
  AS1.AS_TYPE,
  AS1.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
 FROM
  TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS AS1
  INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_EQUITY EQT ON (AS1.AS_NUMBER = EQT.AS_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC ON (AS1.as_number = ALLOC.as_number)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT ON (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK ON (ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE ON (AS1.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE)

UNION ALL

SELECT
  AS1.AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
  AS1.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.Record_Status,
  AS1.Approval_Status,
  AS1.Transaction_Type,
  AS1.Value_Date,
  AS1.ASSET_CLASS_CODE,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
  NULLIF(0, 0) TENOR,
  GS.Price_Per_100,
  GS.AWARDED_FACE_VALUE AS FACE_VALUE,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Number_of_shares,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_per_share,
  AS1.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
  NULLIF(0, 0) RATE,
  GS.YTM,
  AS1.ISSUE_CODE,
  ACCT.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
  AS1.ACCOUNT_OFFICER AS MAKER,
  ACCT.ARRANGEMENT,
  ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE,
  ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE,
  ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE,
  BANK.REGION_ID,
  AS1.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
  ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE AS ISSUER_CODE,
  AS1.AS_TYPE,
  AS1.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
FROM
  TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS AS1
  INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_GS GS ON (AS1.AS_NUMBER = GS.AS_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC ON (AS1.as_number = ALLOC.as_number)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT ON (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK ON (ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE ON (AS1.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE)
UNION ALL

SELECT
  AS1.AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
  AS1.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.Record_Status,
  AS1.Approval_Status,
  AS1.Transaction_Type,
  AS1.Value_Date,
  AS1.ASSET_CLASS_CODE,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
  NULLIF(0, 0) TENOR,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_Per_100,
  PREF.FACE_VALUE,
  PREF.DONE_NUMBER_OF_SHARES,
  PREF.Price_per_share,
  AS1.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
  NULLIF(0, 0) RATE,
  PREF.YTM,
  AS1.ISSUE_CODE,
  ACCT.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
  AS1.ACCOUNT_OFFICER AS MAKER,
  ACCT.ARRANGEMENT,
  ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE,
  ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE,
  ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE,
  BANK.REGION_ID,
  AS1.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
  ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE AS ISSUER_CODE,
  AS1.AS_TYPE,
  AS1.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
FROM
  TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS AS1
  INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_PREF PREF ON (AS1.AS_NUMBER = PREF.AS_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC ON (AS1.as_number = ALLOC.as_number)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT ON (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK ON (ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE ON (AS1.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE)
 UNION ALL

SELECT
  AS1.AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
  AS1.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.Record_Status,
  AS1.Approval_Status,
  AS1.Transaction_Type,
  AS1.Value_Date,
  AS1.ASSET_CLASS_CODE,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
  NULLIF(0, 0) TENOR,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_Per_100,
  PREP.FACE_VALUE,
  PREP.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_SHARES,
  PREP.Price_per_share,
  AS1.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
  NULLIF(0, 0) RATE,
  NULLIF(0, 0) YTM,
  AS1.ISSUE_CODE,
  ACCT.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
  AS1.ACCOUNT_OFFICER AS MAKER,
  ACCT.ARRANGEMENT,
  ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE,
  ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE,
  ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE,
  BANK.REGION_ID,
  AS1.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
  ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE AS ISSUER_CODE,
  AS1.AS_TYPE,
  AS1.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
FROM
  TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS AS1
  INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_PREP PREP ON (AS1.AS_NUMBER = PREP.AS_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC ON (AS1.as_number = ALLOC.as_number)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT ON (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK ON (ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE ON (AS1.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE)

UNION ALL

SELECT
  AS1.AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
  AS1.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.Record_Status,
  AS1.Approval_Status,
  AS1.Transaction_Type,
  AS1.Value_Date,
  AS1.ASSET_CLASS_CODE,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
  NULLIF(0, 0) TENOR,
  OSEC.Price_Per_100,
  OSEC.AWARDED_FACE_VALUE AS FACE_VALUE,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Number_of_shares,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_per_share,
  AS1.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
  NULLIF(0, 0) RATE,
  OSEC.YTM,
  AS1.ISSUE_CODE,
  ACCT.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
  AS1.ACCOUNT_OFFICER AS MAKER,
  ACCT.ARRANGEMENT,
  ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE,
  ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE,
  ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE,
  BANK.REGION_ID,
  AS1.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
  ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE AS ISSUER_CODE,
  AS1.AS_TYPE,
  AS1.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
 FROM
  TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS AS1
  INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_OSEC OSEC ON (AS1.AS_NUMBER = OSEC.AS_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC ON (AS1.as_number = ALLOC.as_number)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT ON (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK ON (ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE ON (AS1.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE)

 UNION ALL

SELECT
  AS1.AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.CREATE_TIME_STAMP,
  AS1.ORIGINAL_AS_NUMBER,
  AS1.Record_Status,
  AS1.Approval_Status,
  AS1.Transaction_Type,
  AS1.Value_Date,
  AS1.ASSET_CLASS_CODE,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
  ACCT.ACCOUNT_NAME,
  NULLIF(0, 0) TENOR,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_Per_100,
  NULLIF(0, 0) FACE_VALUE,
  PF.AWARDED_NUMBER_OF_UNITS AS number_of_shares,
  NULLIF(0, 0) Price_per_share,
  AS1.SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
  NULLIF(0, 0) RATE,
  NULLIF(0, 0) YTM,
  AS1.ISSUE_CODE,
  ACCT.USER_ID AS ACCOUNT_OFFICER,
  AS1.ACCOUNT_OFFICER AS MAKER,
  ACCT.ARRANGEMENT,
  ACCT.PRODUCT_CODE,
  ACCT.TBG_UNIT_CODE,
  ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE,
  BANK.REGION_ID,
  AS1.COUNTER_PARTY_CODE,
  ISSUE.ENTITY_CODE AS ISSUER_CODE,
  AS1.AS_TYPE,
  AS1.REQ_TBG_UNIT_ID
 FROM
  TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS AS1
  INNER JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_POOLED_FUNDS PF ON (AS1.AS_NUMBER = PF.AS_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.IMS_AS_ALLOCATION ALLOC ON (AS1.as_number = ALLOC.as_number)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.AMS_ACCOUNT ACCT ON (ALLOC.Account_number = ACCT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_BANK_BRANCH_UNIT BANK ON (ACCT.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE = BANK.BANK_BRANCH_UNIT_CODE)
  LEFT JOIN TBSDB2P.dbo.TBS_ISSUE ISSUE ON (AS1.ISSUE_CODE = ISSUE.ISSUE_CODE)

GO;
```